# Ubuntu 22.04 USB Webcam always needs to be unplugged and replugged after boot

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, 22.04, webcam

I have an old [Microsoft LifeCam VX-1000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GE9XQ2) that works pretty much flawlessly in Ubuntu 22.04 except for the fact that it never gets detected immediately after a boot. Every time I reboot, I always have to unplug the USB connector and plug it back in, and then it works perfectly fine.

If I run `lsusb` immediately after boot, the Camera shows up as a generic `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0000:0000  USB camera`, however, after unplugging it and plugging it back in, `lsusb` shows it as `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 045e:00f7 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-1000`

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the system startup logs with the terminal command  `sudo journalctl  -b 0` to see your system detect hardware at startup. Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you reconnect the camera. Compare